# Is there a builtin (or standard) sound recorder with OS X?

Tags: macos

I need to make some voice notes, preferably in wave format (I can convert mp3 to wave if need be). I have really, really simple needs, as in Windows 7's "Sound Recorder" works fine for me. I can't seem to find anything built in with OS X. What's the go to app for this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In Mac OS X 10.6 and newer, use QuickTime Player. **File** > **New Audio Recording**.

Comment: Would not have thought to go to QuickTime!

Comment: nice, QT ftw - that shiz' been around since the 90s.

Comment: nice, QT ftw - that shiz' been around since the 90s.